# xml minidom - get the full content of childnodes text

Tags: python, xml

I have a Test.xml file as:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
  <SetupConf>
  <LocSetup>
    <Src>
      <Dir1>C:\User1\test1</Dir1>
      <Dir2>C:\User2\log</Dir2>
      <Dir3>D:\Users\Checkup</Dir3>
      <Dir4>D:\Work1</Dir4>
      <Dir5>E:\job1</Dir5>       
    </Src>
  </LocSetup>
  </SetupConf>
```

Where node depends on user input. In "Dir" node it may be 1,2,5,10 dir structure defined. As per requirement I am able to extract data from the Test.xml with help of @Padraic Cunningham using below Python code:

```
from xml.dom import minidom
from StringIO import StringIO
dom = minidom.parse('Test.xml')
Src = dom.getElementsByTagName('Src')
output = ", ".join([a.childNodes[0].nodeValue for node in Src for a in  node.getElementsByTagName('Dir')])
print [output]
```

And getting the output:

```
C:\User1\test1, C:\User2\log, D:\Users\Checkup, D:\Work1, E:\job1
```

But the expected output is:

```
['C:\\User1\\test1', 'C:\\User2\\log', 'D:\\Users\\Checkup', 'D:\\Work1', 'E:\\job1']
```

Answer (score 0):

Well it's solved by myself:

```
from xml.dom import minidom
DOMTree = minidom.parse('Test0001.xml')
dom = DOMTree.documentElement
Src = dom.getElementsByTagName('Src')

for node in Src:

    output = [a.childNodes[0].nodeValue for a in node.getElementsByTagName('Dir')]

    print output
```

---

And getting output:
[u'C:\User1\test1', u'C:\User2\log', u'D:\Users\Checkup', u'D:\Work1', u'E:\job1']

---

I am sure there is more simple another way .. please let me know.. Thanks in adv.